# Amazon EC2 - Does the 160GB drive charges for IOPS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

If I buy a Standard Small EC2 instance, it comes with a 160GB. But does this 160GB drive is an EBS drive? Or simply storage for the OS...

And also am I charged for the IOPS on that 160GB drive?

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing you should ask Amazon customer service.

Comment: I agree and I'm surprised at the number of questions lately that could be quickly and better answered by a phone call or email to the vendor.

Comment: Take it as a compliment, people would rather trust your opinion over that of a vendor. ...I can't entirely say I blame them, either.

Comment: @Sirex while this is true in most cases, billing isn't something that I want to hear about from a third party :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- EBS-backed instances have a certain amount of ephemeral instance-local storage (160GB in your case).
- IOPS charges are charged against EBS volumes, which means the Root volume for EBS-backed instances, plus any attached EBS volumes.
- Instance-local storage is not EBS

Therefore, you will not be charged IOPS for ephemeral instance-local storage.